# Why does an integer comparison result in no temporary index in MariaDB?

Tags: query-performance, mariadb, execution-plan, mariadb-10.5

I am running a query on a table (`transaction_items`, c. 12 million rows) that has a many-to-many relationship with another table, and I wish to group `transaction_items` by this relationship.

To do this, my query:

1. Contains a sub-query over the many-to-many relationship's junction table (`transaction_item_defects`, c. 12 million rows), which it groups by the `transaction_item_id` key, and concatenates the relation's key (`product_defect_id`)
2. Left-joins this subquery
3. Groups the outer-query by the `product_defect_id` concatenation

This query is generated by an ORM. I have encountered a case where the outer-query has a `WHERE` condition over `transaction_item_id`, in which the argument is supplied as an integer. Under such conditions, as far as I can tell the query-planner does not use an index when joining the derived sub-query to the outer-query — the performance of this is terrible, with the query taking in excess of a minute.

I've investigated further, and have discovered that if I change the argument for the condition on `transaction_item_id` to a string, the query-planner instead generates a temporary index, which I believe it uses to join the derived sub-query to the outer-query. In this case the query is far more performant, taking less than a second.

**My question:**
Why does changing the type from integer to string, when performing a comparison against an integer column, cause this change in the execution-plan?

Please note that I understand my example may seem a bit contrived — I have pared the query generated by the ORM down to the essential elements that reproduce the change in query plan. I'm open to and grateful for any incidental advice on how I can employ a better strategy to achieve my aim, but my main concern is the question above: why does the argument type change the behaviour (in what, to me, is a counter-intuitive way)?

**ORM query (integer condition; non-performant)**

```
EXPLAIN SELECT 1
FROM
    `transaction_items`
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            `transaction_item_defects`.`transaction_item_id`,
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `product_defect_id`) AS `defects`
        FROM
            `transaction_item_defects`
        GROUP BY
            `transaction_item_defects`.`transaction_item_id`) `transaction_item_defects` ON `transaction_items`.`transaction_item_id` = `transaction_item_defects`.`transaction_item_id`
WHERE
    `transaction_items`.`transaction_item_id` IN(10577645)
```

**ORM query result**:

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | transaction_items | ref | PRIMARY,transaction_item_valid_start,transaction_item_validity | transaction_item_valid_start | 4 | const | 3 | Using where; Using index |
| 1 | PRIMARY |  | ALL |  |  |  |  | 11039311 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
| 2 | DERIVED | transaction_item_defects | index |  | transaction_item_id | 12 |  | 11039311 | Using where; Using index |

**Modified query (string condition; performant)**

```
# ORM EXPLAIN
EXPLAIN SELECT 1
FROM
    `transaction_items`
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            `transaction_item_defects`.`transaction_item_id`,
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `product_defect_id`) AS `defects`
        FROM
            `transaction_item_defects`
        GROUP BY
            `transaction_item_defects`.`transaction_item_id`) `transaction_item_defects` ON `transaction_items`.`transaction_item_id` = `transaction_item_defects`.`transaction_item_id`
WHERE
    `transaction_items`.`transaction_item_id` = '10577645'
```

**Modified query result**

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | transaction_items | ref | PRIMARY,transaction_item_valid_start,transaction_item_validity | transaction_item_valid_start | 4 | const | 3 | Using where; Using index |
| 1 | PRIMARY |  | ref | key0 | key0 | 5 | docker.transaction_items.transaction_item_id | 2 |  |
| 2 | LATERAL DERIVED | transaction_item_defects | ref | transaction_item_id | transaction_item_id | 4 | docker.transaction_items.transaction_item_id | 1 | Using where; Using index |

**Table schemata**

```
CREATE TABLE `transaction_items` (
  `transaction_item_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `legacy_transaction_item_type` enum('inventory_item','transaction_item') DEFAULT NULL,
  `legacy_transaction_item_id` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` enum('order','inventory','appraisal') NOT NULL,
  `fidelity` enum('contiguous','pooled','batch') NOT NULL,
  `valid_start` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(6),
  `valid_end` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999',
  `log_request_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `reference_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cross_reference_id` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_id` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `inventory_location_id` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `origin_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `instance_definition` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL CHECK (json_valid(`instance_definition`)),
  PERIOD FOR `valid_period` (`valid_start`, `valid_end`),
  PRIMARY KEY (`transaction_item_id`,`valid_period` WITHOUT OVERLAPS),
  UNIQUE KEY `transaction_item_valid_start` (`transaction_item_id`,`valid_start`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `transaction_item_validity` (`transaction_item_id`,`valid_start`,`valid_end`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  KEY `log_request_id` (`log_request_id`),
  KEY `reference_id` (`reference_id`),
  KEY `cross_reference_id` (`cross_reference_id`),
  KEY `transaction_id` (`transaction_id`),
  KEY `inventory_location_id` (`inventory_location_id`),
  KEY `origin_id` (`origin_id`),
  KEY `reference_location` (`type`,`reference_id`,`inventory_location_id`),
  KEY `reference_transaction` (`reference_id`,`transaction_id`,`type`),
  KEY `fidelity` (`fidelity`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `transaction_items_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`reference_id`) REFERENCES `references` (`reference_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `transaction_items_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`cross_reference_id`) REFERENCES `references` (`reference_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `transaction_items_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`transaction_id`) REFERENCES `transactions` (`transaction_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `transaction_items_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`inventory_location_id`) REFERENCES `inventory_locations` (`inventory_location_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `transaction_items_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`origin_id`) REFERENCES `transaction_items` (`transaction_item_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 WITH SYSTEM VERSIONING
```

```
CREATE TABLE `transaction_item_defects` (
  `transaction_item_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `product_defect_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `transaction_item_id` (`transaction_item_id`,`product_defect_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `product_defect_id` (`product_defect_id`,`transaction_item_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `transaction_item_defects_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`product_defect_id`) REFERENCES `product_defects` (`product_defect_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 WITH SYSTEM VERSIONING
```

Comment: The query doesn't make sense. It simply selects a row with `1` for each row in `transaction_items` with ```transaction_items.transaction_item_id = 10577645```

Comment: Having more than 2 `UNIQUE` (or `PRIMARY`) keys is usually a no-no.  Re-think the indexes on `transaction_items`.

Comment: @Akina I should’ve been clearer about this, but I’ve removed everything from the query that isn’t relevant to my question, including the actual `SELECT` statement. I’m also aware it’s pointless to `GROUP BY` a primary key selection; the reason I’ve posted is that I don’t understand why using a string condition changes the query-plan

Comment: We already know that the posted query is a simplification, but based on what we can actually see, I'd be inclined to think that the plan changes because you change the predicate (from `transaction_item_id IN(...)` to `transaction_item_id = ...`), not because you change the data type.

Answer (score 1):

(This is a guess...)

These are redundant:

```
  UNIQUE KEY `transaction_item_valid_start` (`transaction_item_id`,`valid_start`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `transaction_item_validity` (`transaction_item_id`,`valid_start`,`valid_end`) USING BTREE,
```

Changing them to these *may* help:

```
  UNIQUE KEY `transaction_item_valid_start` (`valid_start`, `transaction_item_id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `transaction_item_validity` (`transaction_item_id`,`valid_start`,`valid_end`) USING BTREE,
```

Note that I flipped the columns in the first one.  This may keep it from being picked while maintaining the uniqueness constraint.

The second one was changed to a plain `INDEX`, since there is no need for it to be `UNIQUE` since the other one is a subset.

`PERIOD FOR` is a brand new feature in MariaDB 10.5; perhaps it has some birthing pains.  If you don't get satisfaction here, file a bug report at jira.mariadb.org .